# Javascript function not able to grab height css attribute

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following site:

http://www.pachamber.org/www/advocacy/index.php

When a user clicks the 'General Commerce' href tag towards the bottom, it should slide out the hidden contents. All of the other tags work correctly except this one.

The function behaves unexpectedly only in IE. It looks to be fine in Chrome and FF. When debugging the function, it seems not not grab the `height` attribute from the div:

`<div id="general" style="display: none; height: 30px; overflow: hidden">`

The `height` attribute is showing as 1px on this line:

`this.height = parseInt(this.obj.style.height);`

Here is the snippit of HTML and the function call:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6">
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" style="width: 100%;">
      <div class="subheading2"  style="border-bottom: thin solid gray; cursor: pointer; color: #000099" onClick="doSlideOut('general');"><a name="general"></a>General Commerce</div>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
<div id="general" style="display: none; height: 30px; overflow: hidden">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6">
<tr>
    <td width="53%">
        &bull; <a href="gc/testimony/index.php" >Testimony &amp; Comments</a>
    </td>
    <td width="47%">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Any ideas what I am missing?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered using jQuery (or equivalent)? It would make that a whole lot easier.

Comment: Matt - I have not. (As you can probably tell)This is some really old code.

Comment: Ya, I saw that. What you could do use jQuery and rewrite all the animation functions. Its not that hard, but it would really help with problems like these.

Comment: I clicked the link you mentioned and it slid down just fine, showing `• Testimony & Comments`

Comment: @MatthewJordan via IE? I'm having issues with IE 9. Chrome and FF look fine.

Comment: @MatthewJordan: Broken in IE9 in Compatibility Mode.

Comment: Is it possible that `this.obj` is not getting the element you're looking for? What happens if you try `alert(this.obj.style.height);` or instead, try `alert(document.getElementById('general').style.height);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Beware of id and name attribute when using getElementById in Internet Explorer](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200802/beware_of_id_and_name_attribute_mixups_when_using_getelementbyid_in_internet_explorer/) describes the stupid behaviour of IE which causes the problem of yours.

If there are two elements with the same value for `id` and `name` (in your case its the div with id `general-commerce` and the link `General Commerce`) IE will grab one of both of them when using getElementById.

The solution would be to change either the name-attribute of the link or the id of the div-container.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I saw was and error in your script.

[image: firbug error]

Errors like these break JS from running properly.

Check out one of [my websites](http://www.howgreatthouart.com/) to see how to do this with jQuery (look at the links under "Our Curriculum").

```
$('.lgroup').on('click', function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass('directLink')) {
        return true
    } else {
        $('.links').slideUp();
        $('.lgroup').removeClass('lactive');
        if ($(this).next().css('display') == 'block') {
            $(this).next().slideUp()
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('lactive').next().slideDown()
        }
    }
});
```